# Presentation of a CHAID decision tree

Tags: statistics, classification, decision-tree

Would anyone please tell me how to effectively present a large CHAID decision tree with 4 levels and 550 nodes? Any sample manuscripts are appreciated. I can't figure out an effective way to present the tree in a manuscript. Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe summarize it in a table? I usually do that.

Comment: Thanks. David. Can you give me an example of what the table should be? What kind of information (p values, thresholds, percentages) should be included? SPSS also provides a table of nodes but it is still a big table.